# My Prefix and Suffix Missing Eyes!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

```
If my prefix had an id, its photo would have only one eye.

If my suffix had a body, its body would have only one eye.

My infix: You are a letter.

Me: My shape is for better.
```

Hint:

> What legitimatey has only one eye on this planet?

Comment: Is the answer rot 13 (Cbgngb)?? Guessed this completely on the basis of your hint by the way. @risky

Comment: @LakshaySura No, not it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> square

If my prefix had an id, its photo would have only one eye.

> squ -- if squ had an id, it would be squid -- squids have only one eye.

If my suffix had a body, its body would have only one eye.

> are -- pirates make the sound "are" -- if the sound had a body, it would be a pirate!

My infix: You are a letter.

> quar -- you: u, are: r, a: a, letter: q

Me: My shape is for better.

> shape suggests a shape, for suggests 4 sided.

Comment: And would you mind explaining your hint as well.

Comment: On the prefix one, those animals definitely have two eyes.  The word only has one "i", but when you add "id" to a prefix, lots of prefixes end up as a word with only one "i".

Comment: Which type of squid has one eye? The ones I've heard about have two.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Usurper

If my prefix had an id, its photo would have only one eye.

> **U.S.** - if the United States had ID, it would probably feature the [Eye of Providence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence).

If my suffix had a body, its body would have only one eye.

> **Per** is an abbreviation for [Perseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perseus_(constellation)). The embodiment of this constellation would be the Greek mythological hero Perseus who, although was not cycloptic, has the following story associated to him:
>  *"Perseus sought the Greae, sisters of the Gorgons, to demand the whereabouts of the Hesperides, the nymphs tending Hera's orchard. The Graeae were three perpetually old women, who shared a single eye. As the women passed the eye from one to another, Perseus snatched it from them, holding it for ransom in return for the location of the nymphs."*

My infix: You are a letter.

> **U r p** sounds like "You are P"

Me: My shape is for better

> A **usurper** is an illegitimate or controversial claimant to power who would prefer their shape on the "throne" rather than any legitimate figure.

Comment: Not the answer, but you're on the right track for part of the riddle!